# How to use convert_obj_three.py to convert an OBJ to JSON

Tags: python, json, three.js

I have exported a 3d model into `.obj` format but I do not know how to run a python script to convert it into `.js` format.

The problem is that I do not know anything about python programming language or how to run python scripts or execute command lines but all I want to do is to display my 3D model in html.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Blender plugin that allows you to directly export JSON format for three.js.

You can find more about it [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)